# s3 "principal value is invalid " even if I am using the correct arn:aws:iam statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is my json rule:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt14xxxxxxxxxx7",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/me",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have used the `arn:aws:iam` code that is I have downloaded from IAM credendial report. But neither my `:root` or my `user/me` does work. It's like my `arn:aws:iam` code is not valid... The validation window tells *Principal value is invalid - xxxxxxxxxx:user/me*

Does anyone have already had this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem:
I simply needed to put

```
"Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:root"
                ]
            },
```

I do not understand why the previous was not a valid principal, I guess because of the `"AWS:"` part.